# Jsfiddle code is valid, but will not run

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I revised the code that I had previously had a problem on, fixing all the errors and checking multiple times on different "lint" sites. 
Just to make sure that the code works in Jsfiddle, I clicked on JShint and was told that all was valid, however, would not run when I click the button to do so.
sample code to create link:

```
    (function (g) { "use strict"; //g = game
g = this[g] = function () {
    var answer;
    //pre game
    answer = prompt(g.msg[0]); //instruction prompt asks if youve played game
    if (answer === 'no') {
```

etc etc.
http://jsfiddle.net/ShiiFtyyMendoza/NsVvU/12/

Comment: The console has the answer: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'zork_clone' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

The error I'm seeing in the console when trying to run this on jsFiddle is : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'zork_clone' of undefined.

The string 'zork_clone' only exists in two places in your code; the function name executed in line 95, and the string passed in to your module on line 92.

Tracing that parameter in, we see the error thrown from line 2 : `g = this[g] = function () {` which tells me that `this` is undefined when that code is executed.

I believe that in your case `this` is undefined because you're executing within the scope of a 'self-executing anonymous function' rather than an object declared using the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems I can see in the page

**onload event problem**
Your fiddle script is setup to execute after onload event, yet again in your script you are registering another onload handler.
**To fix** this in the left panel of the fiddle under `Frameworks & Extensions` in second select field select `No Wrap - in <body>`

**Anonymous function problem**
From what I can understand you are trying to create a function with variable name(in this case function with name `zork_clone`) in the global scope(ie in `window`). But you are using `strict` mode inside the inner function. Here what you need is `this` to point to the `window` object which is the normal case if you are not using `strict` mode, this changes in the `strict` mode. As you can [find here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode#.22Securing.22_JavaScript) in strict mode `this` has to be explicit, otherwise it will have the value `undefined` that is what is happening in your case.
**The fix** is to use `window` global variable instead of using `this` inside the anonymous function.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Tffsq/)